# Should Fragments Be Used In the Back Stack

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-orientation

I know I *can* use a `Fragment` and have it added to the back stack, like so:

```
Fragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment).addToBackStack("my_fragment").commit();
```

Then I can handle changes in `onBackStackChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    boolean hasBackStack = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0;
    handleBackStackChanges(hasBackStack);
}
```

But the nagging question I have is whether or not I *should*.

---

The initial reason for this question is because of my desire to implement a **persistant** navigation drawer. One that is available at any point within the application, even if the navigation drawer icon (hamburger icon) is not present, with a swipe from the left edge of the screen.

This leaves me with two options; first I can have a single `Activity` that has a navigation drawer and hosts all of the `Fragments`, or I can have multiple `Activities` that each contain a navigation drawer.

Initially I was drawn to the first option, considering the [navigation drawer sample](http://developer.android.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/index.html) uses fragments for each drawer option. This method would also allow me to easily implement the navigation drawer icon animation in `onBackStackChanged`:

```
public void handleBackStackChanges(boolean hasBackStack) {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mDrawerArrow, "progress", hasBackStack ? 0 : 1).start();
    ...
}
```

But the sample is essentially a "flat" application, it doesn't handle any back stack changes (except for back to the `MainActivity`, which doesn't have a navigation drawer). And upon further development I have come across some difficulties with using a single `Activity`. Especially when handling orientation changes, and changes within the `Toolbar`.

So now I am thinking it may be simpler to use multiple `Activities`. Every `Activity` would extend a custom `NavigationDrawerActivity`. The `MainAcitivity` would have a `Fragment` for each navigation drawer item. Then each subsequent `Activity` (called from one of the `Fragments` in the `MainActivity`) would have a `NavigationDrawer` of its own, with a reference to which navigation drawer item the original `Activity` was in.

I can see this route presenting its own problems as well. Handling the navigation drawer icon animation, and handling the back stack when an item is selected from the drawer.

My question is essentially this: has anyone faced these problems already, and is there a more concrete solution? Are there issues (performance related or otherwise) that I could run into when choosing one option over the other?

Comment: We used multiple activities, and had a custom viewgroup that contained the logic for the navigation drawer, and we included that in the activity's layout with `<include layout="@layout/left_navigation_drawer"/>`. Now we'd just use Mortar/Flow instead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I had not heard of Flow and Mortar previously, it seems very promising. Though, from what I have read, it seems like a long transition that has its own faults. I don't know if I am prepared to jump on that just yet. I'm starting to lean toward your original implementation.

Comment: Another possible approach is the dynamic installation of the navigation drawer, akin to what the MikePenz Material Navigation Drawer library uses. One method call, and the drawer layout gets installed around the activity's layout.